Sharing a page to Facebook only share home page not the page itself
I have a share page underneath the page content which includes a Facebook share button, the link looks correct e.g. at the bottom of this page
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://eagleburra.com.au/contact-us/
But it only links to the site domain url https://eagleburra.com.au/
It is a public link so not sure why this is happening
Is there something else I need in that link?
